Add model path to code to load the model and allow low cpu mem usage
I am trying to use the nous research llama model into my current implementation as I donOt have a local  copy of model saved in my system
My current code implementation has the following:
model_path = "YOUR_DIR/llama/llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
model, tokenizer = load_model_and_tokenizer(model_path,
                       low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
                       use_cache=False,
                       device=device)

I tried reusing my autotokerizer by commmenting out the line and using my autotokenizer as follows:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
model_path = "NousResearch/Llama-2-7b-hf"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("NousResearch/Llama-2-7b-hf")
#model, tokenizer = load_model_and_tokenizer(model_path,
                       low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
                       use_cache=False,
                       device=device)

but it didnt work as it needed  usage of low_cpu_mem_usage=True .
Is there a way I could  embed the nous research model into the original line?
model, tokenizer = load_model_and_tokenizer(model_path,
                       low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
                       use_cache=False,
                       device=device)

